# Pandas excel import changes the Date format

Tags: python, excel, pandas, date

Im learning python (3.6 with anaconda) for my studies.

Im using pandas to import a xls file with 2 columns : Date (dd-mm-yyyy) and price.
But pandas changes the date format :

```
xls_file = pd.read_excel('myfile.xls')
print(xls_file.iloc[0, 0])
```

Im getting :

```
2010-01-04 00:00:00
```

instead of :

```
04-01-2010     or at least :  2010-01-04
```

I dont know why hh:mm:ss is added, I get the same result for each row from the Date column. I tried also different things using to_datetime but it didnt fix it.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Dates in Excel aren't stored as a string, they're just a number. When you pull that data out of Excel any formatting is lost. Python applies its own formatting when you print it.

Comment: Thank you for this information, my problem has been fixed anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to define the format that the `datetime` values get printed. There might be a more elegant way to do it but something like that will work:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   id       date
0   1 2017-09-12
1   2 2017-10-20

# Specifying the format
In [16]: print(pd.datetime.strftime(df.iloc[0,1], "%Y-%m-%d"))
2017-09-12
```

If you want to store the date as string in your specific format then you can also do something like:

```
In [17]: df["datestr"] = pd.datetime.strftime(df.iloc[0,1], "%Y-%m-%d")
In [18]: df
Out[18]:
   id       date     datestr
0   1 2017-09-12  2017-09-12
1   2 2017-10-20  2017-09-12

In [19]: df.dtypes
Out[19]:
id                  int64
date       datetime64[ns]
datestr            object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine with pd.datetime.strftime(df.iloc[0,1], "%Y-%m-%d")